# Stripping microdata from an XHTML with PHP - using RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, html, xhtml, microdata

First: I've read the general; don't use RegEx on XHTML arguments like this one: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and I do understand how RegEx will fail on nested XHTML or XML nodes.

I don't see why manipulating attributes of an XML alone should break using RegEx. So there seems to be exceptions to the general rule. Attributes are always contained in a single node starting with a `<` and ending with a `>` any other `< or >` in between would break the XML so such can't occur.

Now I'd like to clean an XHTML string of any microdata it might contain. That is any attributes `itemscope`, `itemtype`, `itemprop`, `itemid` and `itemref`. Something like this:

```
...
<body itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<div itemprop="maincontent">content</div>
...
```

What's the best way to do this in PHP?

Comment: If you want to clean the microdata attributes out of HTML, then HTMLPurifier or htmltidy might suffice. Neither knows about the html5 attributes and will remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd actually suggest:

1. Loading the string with something like SimpleXML.
2. Removing the attributes you are interested in flushing.
3. Saving it back to a string.

There are a bunch of namespace issues that I'm not sure how you'd have to handle, but that will probably be cleaner/happier than trying to build one or more regex expressions and make sure you don't miss anything.

EDIT: turns out SimpleXML won't work (limited modification capabilities) but DOM will. Something like this:

```
$data=<<<END1
<body itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<div itemprop="maincontent">content</div>
</body>
END1;

$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($data);

// find every relevant node
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$attr = $xpath->query("//@itemscope|//@itemprop|//@itemtype");
foreach ($attr as $entry) {
  $entry->parentNode->removeAttribute($entry->nodeName);
}
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

You'd have to modify it to include all the attributes you want to remove, and like I said I have no clue how it would deal with namespaces, but its a start.

Comment: Looks great. One more thing, There can be meta tags in the body due to the microdata stuff. I thought I could select those with xpath 'body//meta' but somehow it does not work yet...

Comment: The query above works on attributes: I think you want to do `//body/meta` but also realize that since those aren't attributes you can't use `removeAttribute` on them. Easiest way would be to put tags in a separate xpath loop and use `removeChild` instead.

Comment: that I understood. I did make it a separate xpath loop and did use removeChild. That's on the manual. `$xml->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("meta")->length;` gives back the actual number of tags while all xpath versions I tried even `$xpath->query("//body")->length` gives back `0`. I was wondering what my xpath problem is. Trying the same with an attribute `$xpath->query("//@itemscope")->length;`works though...

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you might be doing wrong without code, but `$blk = $xpath->query("//meta");
forreach($blk as $t){
$t->parentNode->removeChild($t);
}` works for me.